# Can't connect to VM from Host in HostOnlyNetwork Configuration

Tags: network-programming, virtual-machine, virtualbox, packer

I am trying to create a VM on my Ubuntu linux machine. The VM I am trying to create is 12.04 Ubuntu 32 bit virtual machine. I have had success creating said VM from a Windows environment, but when I migrated to a 16.04 Ubuntu environment I can't replicate my success. The problem comes from when I chose a HostOnly network for my VM. On my windows computer, after setting the IP and subnet mask using Host network manager on Virtualbox, Upon selection of a VirtualBox host only adapter, I was able to make Packer ssh into my VM. However, when I tried the same thing on my Ubuntu machine, going to preferences -> network, and setting the IP and subnet mask, whenever I select VBoxnet0 and than have Packer attempt to ssh or when I ping into my VM from my Ubuntu machine, I get host unreachable. Both netstat and ifconfig are telling that vboxnet0 is there. Based on what I have written, what might be the reasons I can't connect to my VM?

Comment: This question is not related to programming. It fits better to [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)

Comment: With that little information it's very hard to say what is wrong. Add the command line you run, example template and scripts. Also some debugging output of your network, such as ifconfig etc.

Comment: My Ubuntu host machine is essentially a virtual machine.